# QPrinter runtime error

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, printing

EDIT: I managed to get a compiling and non crashing version. The only thing left is to get the desired output, however this particular question (why it crashes) has been answered so I am closing the question. I will post the working code before the broken one.

Good day! I am trying to create a small example that will simply create a pdf document. Everything compiles, however when the program starts it simply crashes. I am using Qt version 5.0.0

---New working code---

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    QApplication app( argc, argv );

  QTextDocument doc;
  doc.setHtml( "<p>A QTextDocument can be used to present formatted text "
               "in a nice way.</p>"
               "<p align=center>It can be <b>formatted</b> "
               "<font size=+2>in</font> <i>different</i> ways.</p>"
               "<p>The text can be really long and contain many "
               "paragraphs. It is properly wrapped and such...</p>" );
   QPrinter printer;
   printer.setOutputFileName("C:\\Users\\SameTime\\Desktop\\Cutie\\PDFPrintMaybe");
   printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
   doc.print(&printer);
   printer.newPage();

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the project code:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-06-08T10:07:11
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui
QT += printsupport
TARGET = PDFPrintMaybe
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
```

----Old code with error---
And here is the main cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTextDocument>
#include <QPrinter>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTextDocument doc;
    doc.setHtml("<h1>Testing, testing, is this thing on?!</h1>");
    QPrinter printer;
    printer.setOutputFileName("C:\\Users\\SameTime\\Desktop\\Cutie\\PDFPrintMaybe");
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
    doc.print(&printer);
    printer.newPage();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I am a bit at a loss since it is compiling but crashing (almost) instantly when ran.

Comment: Where does your program crash when you run it in a debugger?

Comment: QTextDocument doc; this line

Comment: Still crashes, I managed to get a working version up (still doesn't get the output I want but it isn't crashing) Should I close this thread?

Comment: What did you do one year ago ?

Comment: The problem was something with the configuration as far as I recall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create the objects on the heap otherwise they get automatically deleted when they ran out of scope, then the framework probably tries to delete them again and crashes.

```
QTextDocument *doc = new QTextDocument();
doc->setHtml("<h1>Testing, testing, is this thing on?!</h1>");
QPrinter* printer = new QPrinter();
printer->setOutputFileName("C:\\Users\\SameTime\\Desktop\\Cutie\\PDFPrintMaybe");
printer->setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
doc->print(printer);
printer->newPage();
```